# "User memory limit exceeded" using Random Forest classification

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, random-forest

I am trying to classify using randomForest classification in GEE . However, I always get the error `User memory limit exceeded`, so I assume the number  of the feature are too large.

Nevertheless, I saw many developers can classify even bigger dataset, so I am wondering if there is a better option there?

The code can be accessed via
https://code.earthengine.google.com/23538cf3ed6b667d6e5975cb2864a436

```
var fire= ee.FeatureCollection('users/spatola/recovery_rf_1712').map(function(feature){
    var num = ee.Number.parse(feature.get('CLC_311'));
    return feature.set('CLC_311', num);
  })
var indices= ['EVI_mean','Dnbr','NBR2_mean','NBR2_min','NBR2_max','EVI_min','EVI_max'];
var fire1=  fire.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(indices));
var fire2= fire1.select('Class_R','Dnbr','EVI_max','NBR2_max','imageId')
var bands= ['NBR2_max', 'EVI_max'];
var classProperty= 'Class_R';
var random= fire2.randomColumn('random');
var split_train= 0.8;
var split_test= 0.2;
var trainPartition= random.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random',split_train));
var testPartition= random.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random',split_test));

var RFtrained_c= ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest({
 numberOfTrees: 100,
 minLeafPopulation:2,
 seed: 123,
 })
.setOutputMode('CLASSIFICATION')
.train({
    features: trainPartition,
    inputProperties: bands,
    classProperty: classProperty,
    })
print(RFtrained_c);
var dict =  RFtrained_c.explain();
var test = testPartition.classify(RFtrained_c)
print(test.first())
```

Answer (score 2):

As the FeatureCollection you want to classify is not shared, it's hard to tell whether the number of features is the problem. But unless you have hundreds of thousands of points, I don't think the number of points is the problem. As mentioned by @Elmstead, exporting the classified FC might help, using `Export.table.toAsset()`

Also, please be aware that you're using overlapping data for training and testing, as you are using `ee.Filter.lt('random',0.8)` to generate the training data (returns 80% of the data), and `ee.Filter.gte('random',0.2)` for the test data (also returns 80% of the data).

This is how I would split the data in 80% train, 20% test:

```
var trainPartition= fire2.randomColumn({seed: 1}).filter(ee.Filter.gte('random',0.2));
var testPartition= fire2.randomColumn({seed: 1}).filter(ee.Filter.lt('random',0.2));
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might help is if you can execute this process as a task rather than in the console, for example by manipulating the code here that exports an image. I'm not sure what specific command you need for your application, but I do know this will give your task more time to run, if not more memory, before you hit an error.

```
task=ee.batch.Export.image.toAsset(**task_config)
task.start()
```